# Load XML to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario where I wanted to load XML into SQL Server.  What i am curious about is it it faster to dump the xml blob into SQL Server and parse it within SQL Server or parse the xml with in an app like C# and then hand the data off to SQL Server?

I would prefer to grab the xml and just pass it to a SQL Sproc, but wasn't sure if that would be an efficient process?

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both options are viable.

It really depends on what you want to do.

If you want to a solution that does not require an application, then you should go for the first option.

If the only reason you want to write a C# app (option 2) is to pass the xml data into SQL Server, then I will personally go for the first option